# Maximum recursion reached limit error?

Tags: matlab, recursion

When I am trying to made function and then call in a program. it gives recursion error. I have searched  on google about this problem they said loop runs recursively, so you have to debugg the code. I have also tried set(0,'RecursionLimit',10000)but it closed the MATLAB forcefully. Will anyone check it where i made the mistakes in code.

Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached. Use set(0,'RecursionLimit',N) to change the limit. Be aware that exceeding your
available stack space can crash MATLAB and/or your computer.

Error in ismemberBismemberBuiltinTypes

```
function FaceLM = facialplot(image)
img=image;
FaceLM = textread('myfile1.txt') ;
% -- Plot landmarks over the face (unnumbered)
figure(1),
imshow(img)
hold on, plot( FaceLM(:,1), FaceLM(:,2), 'r*')

% -- Plot landmarks over the face (numbered)
figure(2),
imshow(img)
hold on, 

numFaceLM = size( FaceLM(:,1) );

for i = 1:numFaceLM

    text( FaceLM(i,1), FaceLM(i,2), num2str(i));

end
end
```

Comment: I cannot see any recursion here. (The recursion limit will obviously not help, because this just says at what recursion depth Matalb will throw an error.) I suggest you remove/comment out piece by piece from your code untill the error does not show up anymore, in order to find where your recursion is called.

Comment: yes it removes.. thankyou.. Do you have any idea how to read text files from a folder, like in above code i have used textread('myfiles.txt').. i want here that it read the no of files as many as i want. I guess some loop will workout..do you have any idea how to do it?